# Difference between stripboard and breadboard

Tags: mobile-robot, hardware

I'm new around here. I've observed individuals using stripboard.
Could you please explain the difference between a breadboard and a stripboard?
Are  stripboards internally connected ? I've  stripboard with tracks cut into them in certain applications. I'm not sure why this is carried out.

Answer (score 2):

I googled it, and stripboard looks like breadboard, but it's permanent.

Breadboards have spring-loaded clips that hold the leads pushed in, so you can push components in and make electrical connections without soldering. There are no such spring-loaded clips with stripboards, meaning you'd have to solder everything in place.

:EDIT:

Here's a picture of a breadboard. You can see the holes; again there are spring-loaded clips that hold the components once you push them in. In this picture, the "rails" are connected, so the first column is one bus, the second column is one bus, the second-to-last column is one bus, and the last column is one bus. For the interior section, rows a/b/c/d/e are connected and rows f/g/h/i/j are connected.

[image: breadboard]

Here's a picture of a stripboard. Here each row is electrically connected.

[image: stripboard]

Here's a picture of a stripboard that's arranged the same way as a breadboard. You can see the four rails and lots of rows, again separated a/b/c/d/e and f/g/h/i/j.

[image: breadboard-like stripboard]

And finally, maybe what you're asking about, is *perfboard*, which has [metal vias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Via_(electronics)) that can be soldered to, but there are *no* electrical connections between any holes. This would require you to solder jumpers... lots of jumpers lol. The "easiest" way to do this would be to leave the leads long on the through-hole devices and solder jumpers to the leads, or you could lay down the leads and make [solder bridges](https://www.pcbdirectory.com/community/what-is-solder-bridging) between vias,  but really the easier thing would be to use stripboard.

[image: perfboard]

Comment: Are stripboards internally connected like breadboard ?

Comment: There's not really an "internal" to these; they're like prototyping printed circuit boards; they've got holes drilled and connected like a breadboard. I'll add pictures to the answer.

Comment: @Robin - just added the images. Breadboards are no-solder devices with "strips" that connect several holes. Stripboards are solder-only devices with "strips" that connect several holes. Perfboards are solder-only devices that have only electrically isolated through holes.

Comment: So , what do you infer from here ? Are holes of stripboards connected or isolated ? Why are the tracks cut in some cases ?

Comment: Wire wrap is pretty effective for connecting leads on a perfboard.

Comment: @Robin I'm not sure what you're asking or how to answer it. If everything were connected then you couldn't make a useful circuit. If nothing were connected then you'd have perfboard. Stripboard has strips/rows of holes that are electrically connected, which would lets you selectively connect different items based on the strip/row to which you solder the component leads.